# How to "add a folder to PYTHONPATH"?

Tags: python

I have downloaded a package and need to "add it to PYTHONPATH" as indicated in the documentation. How may I do it?

I am using Visual Studio for python, if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

In python you can do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("yourpath to package")
```

From within python. Or you can set your environment variables in Windows after right clicking on 'computer' and selecting properties.

Also it's easy in python to install packaged with 'pip'.

Comment: I have done the sys.append, but ImportError: No module named Kernel

Comment: Does the appended folder have a kernel.py or __init__.py file?

Comment: it has a init but no kernel

Comment: That is an __ init  __.py without the whitespace.

Comment: Add the path to the __folder__ where the `__init__.py` file is in rather than to the `__init__.py` file itself. I.e. `sys.append.path('C:\apath)` which is the folder which contains the kernel folder with the `__init__.py` file.